# Objective-C Decimal to Base 16 Hex conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, hex

Does anyone have a code snippet or a class that will take a long long and turn it into a 16 byte Hex string?

I'm looking to turn data like this

```
long long decimalRepresentation = 1719886131591410351;
```

and turn it into this

```
//Base 16 Hex Output: 17DE435307A07300
```

The %x operator doesn't want to work for me

```
NSLog(@"Hex: %x",decimalRepresentation);
//console : "Hex: 7a072af"
```

As you can see that's not even close.  Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%x` prints an unsigned integer in hexadecimal representation and `sizeof(long long) != sizeof(unsigned)`. See e.g. ["Data Type Size and Alignment"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH207-SW1) in the 64bit transitioning guide.

Use the `ll` specifier (thats two lower-case *L*) to get the desired output:

```
NSLog(@"%llx", myLongLong);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quick!  I haven't tried this on iPhone yet, do you know if it works on the iPhone processor?

Comment: The `printf()` format is well specified, so i wouldn't expect any surprises there.

Comment: You should clarify in your answer that the %llx is actually two lowercase Ls, and not two number ones.  I had to copy and paste your answer to realize this.

Comment: @Justin: Oh, ok - i guess for me *"`long` -> lowercase L"* is hardwired now.